# MySQL query to insert values into table 2 if record absent in table 1

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this query. I am building an API to send friend requests.

The end user will be sending me the email id of the person whom he/she wants to send a frnd request. I need to first check my `user` table against the email id the end user is sending and find out if the email id is present in my `user` table.

**Case1:**

Email id is present in `user` table. I then need to **SELECT** the `user_id` for this user `AS friend_id`.
And then insert into `friend_request` the `user_id` of the person calling the api and `friend_id`. I already get the `user_id` of the user calling the API whenever the API is called.

**Case2:**

Email id is absent in `user` table. I send an email invitation to this user to register into the app.

I am trying to do the mysql query of case1 in one single statement. I was wondering something like this,

```
INSERT INTO friend_request (user_id, friend_id) VALUES (1,4) WHERE EXITS (SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='black@sheep.com');
```

But obviously this will not work and has syntax errors, any idea on how I can achieve this?

Comment: @user what existing rows? I am working on two different tables, `user` and `friend_request` I need to check up against `user` table and insert in `friend_request` table

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just spelling error?

EXITS  => EXISTS

```
INSERT INTO friend_request (user_id, friend_id) VALUES (1,4) 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='black@sheep.com');
```